# finding the locus?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, locus

> let $A$ be the point $(0, 4)$ in the $xy$-plane and let $B$ be the point $(2t, 0)$.
>   Let $L$ be the midpoint of $AB$ and let the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ meets
>   the $y$-axis at $M$. Let $N$ be the midpoint of $LM$. Find the locus of $N$ (as $t$
>   varies).

I was trying this question many times.  I don't know where I have to start. I was thinking that this the locus of circle , because it moving around the midpoint $LM$. I don't know how to do this question..
If anybody help me I would very thankful to him.

Answer (score 1):

We obtain: 
$$L\left(\frac{0+2t}{2},\frac{4+0}{2}\right)$$ or
$$L(t,2)$$ and since $$m_{AB}=\frac{4-0}{0-2t}$$ or
$$m_{AB}=-\frac{2}{t},$$ we obtain $m_{ML}=\frac{t}{2}$ and the equation of the line $ML$ is
$$y-2=\frac{t}{2}(x-t),$$ which for $x=0$ gives $y_{M}=2-\frac{t^2}{2}$.

Thus, $M(0,2-\frac{t^2}{2})$, $N\left(\frac{t}{2},2-\frac{t^2}{4}\right)$, which gives the answer:
$$y=2-x^2.$$